# $f(x) = \sin\frac{1}{x}+2x\cos\frac{1}{x}$ is not of bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, bounded-variation

Let $f: [-1,1] \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ such that

$f(x) = \sin\frac{1}{x}+2x\cos\frac{1}{x}$ for $x$ not equal to $0$

and $f(0) = 0$.

I need to show that $f$ is not of bounded variation.

I have shown that $g(x)$ = $\sin\frac{1}{x}$ for $x$ not equal to $0$ and $g(0) =0$ and $h(x)$ = $2x\cos\frac{1}{x}$ for $x$ not $0$ and $0$ for $x$ = $0$ are not of bounded variation.

But I don't think I can say anything about $f$ from here?

Help, please.

Comment: $-1 \le \sin \frac1x \le 1$ for $x \not=0$ which looks bounded to me

Comment: How did you prove that $\sin(1/x)$ is not of bounded variation?Repeat the proof again. You will find that those partitions you chose are also available here. Beacuse when $\sin(1/x)=\pm1$, we have $\cos(1/x)=0$.

Comment: @Henry The OP is talking about the function to be of bounded VARIATION, not about the function been bounded.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)$ is not bounded because $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin(1/x)$ does not exist, because if you
Take $x_n=\frac{1}{n\pi}, x_n'=\frac{1}{(n+1/2)\pi}$, then $\sin n\pi \ne \sin (n+1/2) \pi$

Comment: My question is how do I show it is not of bounded "variation"